# Why can't I pickle a multiprocessing.Manager().Queue handle to a file and load it by another process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipc, message-queue

**Process 1**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import dill
q = mp.Manager().Queue()
with open("/tmp/q.bin", "wb") as fh:
  fh.write(dill.dumps(q))
```

**Process 2**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import dill

with open("/tmp/q.bin", "rb") as fh:
  q = dill.loads(fh.read())
```

Produces this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads
    return load(file, ignore, **kwds)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 473, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 959, in RebuildProxy
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 1007, in AutoProxy
    proxy = ProxyType(token, serializer, manager=manager, authkey=authkey,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 809, in __init__
    self._incref()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 863, in _incref
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 508, in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 758, in answer_challenge
    raise AuthenticationError('digest sent was rejected')
multiprocessing.context.AuthenticationError: digest sent was rejected
```

I know this is because the `multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager` class has an `authkey` field that is set to a unique value per process.. but.. how does this work then when one passes a `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()` through a multiprocessing queue to another process? Doesn't that also have to pickle the queue handle?

I'm essentially in a situation where I want a process that I don't control the spawn of to be able to use a multiprocessing queue to feed work to a worker, and I was hoping to accomplish this by serializing the queue handle to the filesystem and picking it up in the other process.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The idea of using a `manager` is so you can connect to a "server" process via a local port, where you can then get a proxy to the "managed" resource. This is the intended way to use them rather than to make the connection via the file system.

Comment: How do I get another process to connect to the same manager @Aaron? Let’s say I don’t spawn these two processes from the same parent so I can’t just directly pass the queue handle around

Comment: tldr; you run the server in one process, and connect to it via a port from the other processes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager Notice in the example, the address is left blank to indicate localhost, and a port is chosen from the dynamic port range (not required, but good practice to avoid conflicts)

Comment: in answering your newest question, I believe I stumbled upon the solution to why this doesn't work as well.. I would still suggest however that passing objects via a pre-defined port (and password) is better than via a pre-defined file on the file system.